# Suddenly variable watches stopped working(VS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, class

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 trying to debug a C# project. I had some code in one project, and then I merged the code from that project into another one(which didn't affect my code at all). Well, now using this new project variable watches don't work.. like At all.

Like for I have a `List<String> elements;` and in the old project I can hover over and expand elements to see each value in the list. With this new project I can no longer do that. I push the little + and I get the properties "count" and "capacity" and thats it.

```
public class Function
{
protected VariableList arguments;
public VariableList Arguments
{
    get
    {
        return arguments;
    }
}

Variable returnval;
public Variable Returns
{
    get
    {
        return Returns;
    }
}
protected int start;
public Function(int start_,VariableList args,Variable returns) {
       //....
}
public object call(VariableList args,script s)
{
    //....

}

}
```

All of the properties of an instance of this function are filled. But when I hover over such an instance to see the value of the variable while debugging, Now, every properties will just have a red circle by it and say "pointer is no longer valid" while the program is running, and usually the debugger crashes at this point also.

So wtf happened with VS's debugger? is there some special option in the solution or web.config that I'm missing here? (debugging is enabled, btw) or did VS just somehow make a bad solution file or something

Comment: Well I got it to a decent level of debugging by disabling "Just My Code" crap. But thats a global option for my computer, so why does this project not work, yet my old one did with Just My Code enabled? (and with Just My Code disabled, I now get a lot of ugly things I don't need to see)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my web.config was messed up.

It had the debug=true thing, but it had missing closing tags that VS didn't tell me about but apparently messed up subtle things..

This is resolved